# AS3 | getChildByName error

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

When I run the code below I receive the following error:

Scene 1, Layer 'Library', Frame 1, Line 12  1119: Access of possibly undefined property fl_name through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

How can I fix it?

```
09.  mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1)).x=189,00;
10.  mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1)).y=485,55;
11.  mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1)).visible=true;
12.  mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1)).fl_name.text='Something';
```

http://puu.sh/6QSWi.png - image on folder_1
(The digits in the beginning of every line are the numbers of the lines)

Comment: Try `MovieClip(mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1))).fl_name.text`

Comment: or you can try mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1))["fl_name"]["text"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert it to a MovieClip:

```
MovieClip(mc_library.getChildByName("folder_"+(1))).fl_name.text
```